# MS Word - How to shrink a font vertically?

Tags: fonts

I have installed a font that is used to represent ukulele chords (Chordette). It's designed to make sheet music that is easy to play and follow, where you can type both lyrics and the chords. So when you type, for instance, a "C", if you choose that font it will show a C chord (kind of like in this image - https://www.beginnerukuleles.com/wp-content/uploads/Ukulele-chord-diagrams-C-F-G.svg).

The problem is that the ukulele chord font has a lot of blank space at the top. So, when I type a line with the correct chord (in the chord font) right above the lyric line, it makes that line with the chord really high. This makes the whole song take up lots of space on the page, when it doesn't need to. I have the font size at 36 (any smaller and it's too hard to read).

I have tried to play around with paragraph spacing, etc. But it seems like if the font is a certain height, even if there's a lot of empty space, it just won't make the line any narrower. I'd like it if the paragraph spacing could be fixed, and somehow the chord font could be transparent (so it wouldn't cover up the lyrics line above it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play with just one parameter at a time.

The example below is 24pt Calibri with line spacing set at 0.5 (all other parameters in the paragraph dialog are set to 0). The top of the lines, as you can see by the lack of ascenders is cut off.

This should take care of the white space above your chords.

[click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXsQ3.png)